# Mongoid: 2 models with a has_many and has_one relation to a third, sequence of execution seems to make a difference

Tags: ruby, mongoid

```
class Store
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :products
  attr_readonly :products

  def add_product section
    product = Product.new
    section.product = desk
    self.products <<= desk
  end
end

class Section
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :product
end
```

The above code doesn't quite work and the products array is never populated. However, if I simply switched the lines in the add_product method so that it looks like below, things appear to work fine:

```
    self.products <<= desk
    section.product = desk
```

I tried cloning desk and a few other quick and dirty tricks but it didn't make any difference. I am hoping to understand this behavior.